# GLSL: ключевые слова in / out / varying / attribute / uniform

Tags: c, opengl, шейдеры, glsl

Во мноших шейдерах встречаются ключевые слова **`varying`** / **`attribute`**, а в некоторых используются
**`in`** / **`out`**, однако они не соотносятся один к одному. Как их использовать? Что значит **`uniform`**? И какие из них относятся к данным о телах, какие о вершинах, какие об отдельных пикселях?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Описанные ключевые слова являются модификаторами переменных. Они несут в себе следующий смысл:

- **`const`** – обозначает константные переменные, чьи значения не меняются во время выполнения шейдера и известны на момент компиляции. Они общи для всех примитивов, обрабатываемых шейдером.
- **`uniform`** – обозначает константные переменные, чьи значения не меняются во время выполнения шейдера, но неизвестны на момент компиляции и могут задаваться через OpenGL API перед каждым вызовом шейдерной программой. То есть, описывает данные, общие для всего обрабатываемого примитива.
- **`attribute`** – описывает переменные с данными для каждой вершины по отдельности.
- **`varying`** – используется для передачи интерполированных значений между фрагменты и вершинным шейдерами. Доступны для записи в вершинном (vertex) шейдере и только для чтения во фрагментном (fragment) шейдере.

Модификаторы **`varying`** / **`attribute`** и **`in`** / **`out`** применяются с одной целью: переносить данные между разными этапами шейдерной программы. Поэтому их можно определить следующим образом:

- **`in`** – ссылает данные к шейдеру от прошлого этапа
- **`out`** – ссылает данные из шейдера к следующему этапу
- **`attribute`** – то же, что `in` в вершинном шейдере
- **`varying`** – то же, что `out` в вершинном vertex шейдере, и то же, что `in` во фрагментном шейдере

Последние два считаются устаревшими: они не поддерживаются в 4.2 core profile по умолчанию, только в режиме совместимости.

Пример устаревшего вершинного шейдера:

```glsl
#version 110

attribute vec2 position;    
varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = position * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
```

И его обновлённая версия:

```
#version 420

in vec2 position;    
out vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = position * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
```

---

Полезные, использованные ссылки:

- [OpenGL Wiki: модификаторы типов](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL))
- [GameDev: in/out keywords in GLSL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/29673)
- [enSO: differences between an attribute, a uniform, and a varying variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557438/)